# How to add entrypoint in SuiteCRM 8?

Tags: suitecrm

I am trying to add customization in my suitecrm8 using entrypoint but it was not working like the Previous versions of Suitecrm
anyone have idea about this

I am trying to add customization in my suitecrm8 using entrypoint but it was not working
EntryPoint files not working
views files not working

Comment: Did you try to use the legacy approach here?